# no module error for python generated grpc script

Tags: python-3.x, grpc

I'm a new python programmer. Currently, we are switching from python2 to python3, and we found out all the python script generated by grpc have code like this.

```
import dataPlatform_pb2 as dataPlatform__pb2
```

However, python3 do not support this type of relative path import. I need to manually change it to

```
from . import dataPlatform_pb as dataPlatform__pb2
```

Is there any better solution for this problem, it seems a bad practice to changing auto generated code all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything different that you should be doing at this time. We're working on a fix for the issue but it's likely several weeks from being released. In the meantime I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11041) to track adding test coverage representative of your specific use case.

I apologize that we don't have a better answer right now. An easy and practical workaround for the nonce might be to nest your code in a package (directory).